# Hashed identical strings aren't the same when hashed twice

Tags: python, hash, hashlib

I have a login program that hashes a string and stores it in a file to create a new account. When I need to log in, the login detail strings get hashed, and the program checks if the hashed strings have a match in the file. The program works without hashing, but when I hash the identical login details, the hash values are not the same. I have checked and the strings are exactly the same. Here is my code:

```html
import tkinter
import math
import os
import hashlib

# The login function #
def login(username, password, file_path):
    file_new = open(file_path, "a")
    file_new.close()

    file = open(file_path, "r")
    file_content = file.read()
    print(file_content)
    file.close()

    hashed_username = hashlib.md5(bytes(username, "utf-8"))
    hashed_password = hashlib.md5(bytes(password, "utf-8"))
    print(f"Hashed username: {hashed_username}, hashed password: {hashed_password}")

    if f"{hashed_username},{hashed_password}" in file_content[:]:
        return "You were logged in successfully"
    else:
        return "We could not find your account. Please check your spelling and try again."

# The account creation function #
def newaccount(username, password, file_path):
    file_new = open(file_path, "a")
    file_new.close()

    # Reading the file #
    file = open(file_path, "r")
    file_content = file.read()
    print(file_content)
    file.close()

    # Hashing the account details #
    hashed_username = hashlib.md5(bytes(username, "utf-8"))
    hashed_password = hashlib.md5(bytes(password, "utf-8"))
    print(f"Hashed username: {hashed_username}, hashed password: {hashed_password}")
    
    file_append = open(file_path, "a")

    # Checking to see if the details exist in the file #
    if f"{hashed_username},{hashed_password}" in file_content[:]:
        file_append.close()
        return "You already have an account, and were logged in successfully"
    else:
        # Writing the hashed details to the file #
        file_append.write(f"{hashed_username},{hashed_password}\n")
        file_append.close()
        return "New account created."        

logins_path = "Random Scripts\Login Program\logins.txt"

signin_message = input("Would you like to: \n1. Create an account \nor \n2. Log in\n")
if signin_message == "1":
    print("User chose to create account")
    newacc_username = input("Input a username: ")
    newacc_password = input("Input a password: ")
    print(newaccount(newacc_username, newacc_password, logins_path))
elif signin_message == "2":
    print("User chose to log in")
    username = input("Input your username: ")
    password = input("Input your password: ")
    print(login(username, password,logins_path))
else:
    print("Please enter 1 or 2")
```

Comment: input? ouput? expected output?

Comment: @thebjorn Input would be two strings for username and password. The purpose of these strings vary based on whether the user chooses to create an account or login to one.  The expected output is that "You were logged in successfully" assuming that the original account details were given. The output I'm getting is that the program was unable to locate my account. I printed the hashes that I got from the strings used to log in, and they didn't match the ones that were written to the text file when I originally hashed the account details.

Comment: edit your question: strip all the things that work, leave the smallest code possible that doesn't work. Provide the input you used to determine that it didn't work. Provide the output you got. Show us why you believe the output you got is not what you expected. tl;dr show us, don't tell us.\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
hashed_username = hashlib.md5(bytes(username, "utf-8"))
```

This function returns a hash object, and when you print it or write it to a file, you get something like this:

```
<md5 HASH object @ 0x7f8274221990>
```

... which isn't terribly useful.

If you want the actual *text* of the hashes, call `.hexdigest()`:

```
hashed_username = hashlib.md5(bytes(username, "utf-8")).hexdigest()
# returns e.g. "47bce5c74f589f4867dbd57e9ca9f808"
```